# What is the difference between struct node * arr[] and (struct node)* arr[]?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

First option works fine but when I opted for second option `{ (struct node)* arr[] }` I got an declaration error. Please make me know where am I wrong?

Comment: Braces `()` around `struct node` tells the compiler that treat this as a cast operator instead of data type declarator.

Comment: A declaration can't start with `(`.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, the compiler interprets the parentheses to denote the cast operator.  Basically, parentheses are never needed in a declaration like this, so don't use them--they will be interpreted as something else.

---

EDIT:

Parentheses *may* be needed in some declarations, like a function signature for a callback parameter.